# Varnish 3 VCL regex

Tags: regex, caching, varnish

I have been struggling to match this url pattern in varnish 3 vcl

www.example.com/alpha/76/Permanent/

```
if ((req.url ~ "/*/*/Permanent/$")) {
   set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "public, max-age=1400, s-maxage=1400";
   set beresp.ttl = 30m;
   return(deliver);
}
```

but it seems not to match the condition. Any idea where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/*` means zero or more *slashes* (this is not [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))). You should use:

```
^/\w+/\w+/Permanent/$
```

`\w+` would match one or more alphanumeric characters.

Source: [VCL Regex cheat-sheet - Matching with wildcards](https://gist.github.com/dimsemenov/10100415#file-vcl-regex-cheat-sheet-L29)

Comment: it is also matching this one: example.com/Apha/Beta/222/194442/Permanent/, What can be done that it only matches this pattern example.com/alpha/76/Permanent/

Comment: @GoodtheBesT For example, you can use `/\w+/\w+/Permanent/$` - this will only match alphanumeric characters. But it might still match the end of the URL...

Comment: but still it's matching with both patterns example.com/Apha/Beta/222/194442/Permanent/ and  example.com/alpha/76/Permanent/. 

While I want it to match with only this pattern: example.com/alpha/76/Permanent/

Comment: @GoodtheBesT - Try with `^` at the start: `^/\w+/\w+/Permanent/$`: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/vcl.html#backend-probes

Comment: ^ worked, what if to exclude www.example.com not to be cached but other folders and pages cached? can we exclude landing page with any condition?

Comment: @GoodtheBesT - I'm not sure what you mean, but according to https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/vcl.html you can also write conditions for `host`.

Comment: with this condition: ^/\w+/\w+/Permanent/$ it matches perfectly example.com/Alpha/76/permanent/ but if there is something like this example.com/Alpha-ultra/76/permanent/, the condition doesn't work?

Comment: @GoodtheBesT - Instead of `\w+` you can use `[\w\-]+` (alphanumeric+hyphen), or `[^\/]+ (everything besides slash)`. There are many options. Look at [Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for more info.